# Couchdb _session POST not returning set-cookie header in Chrome from Angular 7 app

Tags: authentication, post, cookies, couchdb, angular7

I have an Angular 7 application making a POST request to couchDb _sessions api for authentication. As per the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#cookie-authentication) I should have got a set-cookie header in the response headers but there is no set-cookie header.

This is what the response looks like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5800
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache-control, accept-ranges, etag, server, x-couch-request-id, x-couch-update-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 46
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 20:21:53 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

But if I send the same request through curl:

> curl -v https://example.org/_session -H
>   "Content-Type:application/json
>   " -d '{"name":"user","password":"password"}'

this is what I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 20:25:54 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 46
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
< Set-Cookie: AuthSession=c2JxMTIzOjVDRkVCQ0QyOvjMZQhdhyUqRjmDjl_Hipiz7hxa; Version=1; Expires=Mon, 10-Jun-2019 20:35:54 GMT; Max-Age=600; Path=/; HttpOnly
<
{ [46 bytes data]
100    87  100    46  100    41     46     41  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   154{"ok":true,"name":"username","roles":["sales"]}
```

I tried putting { withCredentials: true} in the header also, still I did not get any cookie. The cookie is also not there in the chrome dev-tools application tab and also in the cookies section of the browser.

```
    const _httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    const headers = _httpHeaders.append('withCredentials', 'true');
    console.log(headers);
    return this._httpService.doAsyncTask(AppConstants.LOGIN_URL, 'POST', data, {headers});
```

How can I come to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Basic Authorization` header and `withCredentials: true` should work.

```
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ':' + password));
const options = { headers: httpHeaders, withCredentials: true };

this._httpService.doAsyncTask(AppConstants.LOGIN_URL, 'POST', data, options);
```

`btoa()` encodes user/password in base-64. The `data` object should not contain the credentials again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @uminder it worked like a charm. But then I have another problem of browser not setting the cookie in the header for GET _sessions api for subsequent request even after using withCredentials: true. I will research more and let you know.